# How to stack multiple columns into one and fill in with column headers

Tags: python, pandas, stack

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Date       Blue     Red      Green
-----------------------------------------
1   1/1/14       55      34         34  
2   1/2/14       36      35         23 
3   1/3/14       23      46         43
4   1/4/14       47      34         55
```

I want to "stack" these color-named columns with unique values into a single "Color" column with each corresponding value attributed, so that there are three columns with for each row, a date (in chronological order, a color label, and the attributed value), with dates repeating for each color.

And so I am trying to get this dataframe:

```
       Date       Color
--------------------------
 1   1/1/14        Blue
 2   1/2/14        Blue
 3   1/3/14        Blue
 4   1/4/14        Blue
 5   1/1/14         Red
 6   1/2/14         Red
 7   1/3/14         Red
 8   1/4/14         Red
 9   1/1/14       Green
10   1/2/14       Green
11   1/3/14       Green
12   1/4/14       Green
------------------------
```

I am trying to "stack" my columns by color, but I am not sure if I should be stacking, melting, or concatenating. Which method should I use to get all of my colors and their values into one column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to "stack" my columns by color, but I am not sure if I should be stacking, melting, or concatenating.

Use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
>>> df.melt(id_vars='Date', var_name='Color', value_name='Value')
      Date  Color  Value
0   1/1/14   Blue     55
1   1/2/14   Blue     36
2   1/3/14   Blue     23
3   1/4/14   Blue     47
4   1/1/14    Red     34
5   1/2/14    Red     35
6   1/3/14    Red     46
7   1/4/14    Red     34
8   1/1/14  Green     34
9   1/2/14  Green     23
10  1/3/14  Green     43
11  1/4/14  Green     55
```

Alternative with a different output:

```
>>> (df.set_index('Date').stack()
       .rename_axis(['Date', 'Color'])
       .reset_index(name='Value'))
      Date  Color  Value
0   1/1/14   Blue     55
1   1/1/14    Red     34
2   1/1/14  Green     34
3   1/2/14   Blue     36
4   1/2/14    Red     35
5   1/2/14  Green     23
6   1/3/14   Blue     23
7   1/3/14    Red     46
8   1/3/14  Green     43
9   1/4/14   Blue     47
10  1/4/14    Red     34
11  1/4/14  Green     55
```